# android sdk. startActivity() moves prog. to background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-2.2-froyo, android-view

I'm  simply trying to change between xml files/layouts.

In my main activity I have `startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,playlist.class), 0);`

I've added the class to my manifest, created the class where the package is com.site.mainactivity, and superclass is android.app.Activity.

I didn't "extends playlist" in my main activity

My logcat only shows "showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection", "InputConnection = android.view.imputmethod.BaseInputConnection@40532b90, active client = false"

When I try to start the new activity/switch layout, my home screen shows, but my app is still running in the background. When I go back to it, the app takes me back to the main screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with how the Activity stack is being maintained. Specifically this is because based on the Manifest properties, an Activity can have different properties that specify how the Activity should be treated by the manifest ie. if it is included in the Activity stack or not and/or Also this could include where the main entrance of the application is, and whether or not an external intent can go to a specific screen in the application.

With manipulation of this it is easy to control. Look up the ActivityManager and how tasks are retrieved and maintained and analyze the design flow of your application. You must fully understand how you want it to work to fully solve your problem. A flow chart would aid you in this diagnosis.

**Learn to control your flow properly.**

Comment: in my manifest I specified the new activity as `<activity android:name = ".playlist" android:enabled = "true" android:screenOrientation = "landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTItleBar"></activity>`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the layout, you can either:

1. call setContentView again
2. use singleTop and launch the same activity but with a different layout
3. close the first Activity with finish() after launching the second

Comment: Humm. I used setContentView, but I wasn't able to call functions. I'll try again quickly...

Comment: Yeah, I'm still not able to call functions are even set the value of a text field after calling setcontentview.

Comment: Ok, I'm able to set the text field by calling text view findviewbyid, but how do I call functions? That seems unnecessary as having to initialize the variables again.

Comment: If you're just changing text values instead of layouts, then you can do something like ((TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv0)).setText("hi"); You can actually modify any layout or view programmatically the same way.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to bypass this hurdle was simply use `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);` as a View and then `setContentView(v)`

I just need to reinitialize events, views, etc so that the program runs as it did before it changed the view.